# MVC is skipping my else?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, model, controller

I have an application where I want to change the navigation bar if a user is logged in.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <p class="navbar-btn">
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Winkelwagen</a>

             @if (@Model == null || Model.isSucces == false)
             {
                  <a href="@Url.Action("Login", "Home")" class="btn btn-default">Inloggen</a>
             }

             else
             {
                  if (Model.isSucces)
                  {
                        <a href ="@Url.Action("Login", "Home")" class="btn btn-default">Mijn Account</a>
                  }
              }

</ul>
```

So when I am logged in the program should go to the if in the else but it never comes so far.

Hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: Why not `@if (Model != null && Model.isSuccess) { ... } else { ... }`? The structure `if () { ... } else { if () { ... } }` seems weird.

Comment: @Corak i did that before but i've got a nullreferenceexeption...

Comment: Hmm... that's what `Model != null` should prevent. And `&&` says, "check right side **if and only if** left side returned true". NullRef shouldn't be possible. -- Btw. I'm not too deep into Razor, but maybe you need another `@` in front of the `if` inside the `else`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a few changes to your code. Simple semantic optimisation, removing and unnecessary @ symbol and closing the paragraph tag.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <p class="navbar-btn">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Winkelwagen</a>

        @if (Model == null || !Model.isSucces)
        {
            <a href="@Url.Action("Login", "Home")" class="btn btn-default">Inloggen</a>
        }
        else if (Model.isSucces)
        {
            <a href ="@Url.Action("Login", "Home")" class="btn btn-default">Mijn Account</a>
        }
    </p>
</ul>
```